# Variance of filtered continuous white noise

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider the 1st order filter $\frac{1}{1+\tau s}$ with $s$ the Laplace operator.

Say $B$ is a white noise process with zero mean and constant variance $Q_B$.

Now let's define $X(t)$ by

- for $t=0$, $X(0)=X_0$
- for $t \gt 0$, $\frac{X}{B}=\frac{1}{1+\tau s}$

**I'm trying to evaluate the variance of $\dot X(t)$. Ideally for any $t$, but at least when ${t\to \infty}$.**

My reasoning was that I could simply write $$\dot X=\frac{B-X}{\tau}$$

Then :

- if $B(t)$ and $X(t)$ are independant
- using the outside knowledge that $\lim_{t\to \infty} var(X(t))=\frac{Q_B}{2\tau}$

I simply deduced

$$\lim_{t\to \infty}var\left(\dot X(t)\right)=\frac{Q_B}{\tau^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\tau}\right)$$

**My questions are :**

- is this right ? In particular, is it really true that $B(t)$ and $X(t)$ are independant ? Simply explicitly calculating $cov\left(B(t),X(t)\right)$ (by replacing $X(t)$ with its integral solution) wants me to say yes, but I tend to get scared with white noise processes as a lot of things you're usually allowed to do are not valid anymore.
- How can I most cleanly evaluate $var(\dot X(t))$ for other, non-$\infty$ values of $t$ ? I'm still quite shaky on Ito calculus etc.

**Additionally,**

I have tried studying
$$Y(t,L)=\frac{X(t+L)-X(t)}{L}={\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)X(t)+e^{-L/\tau}\int_{t}^{t+L} e^{(u-t)/\tau}B(u)du \over L}$$

The variance of which is
$$var\left(Y(t,L)\right)={\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)^2var(X(t))+\left(1-e^{-2L/\tau}\right)\frac{Q_B\tau}{2} \over L^2}$$

Then at least for $t\to \infty$, I replace $var(X(t))$ by $\frac{Q_B}{2\tau}$ and get
$$var\left(Y_{\infty}(L)\right)=\left[\left(e^{-L/\tau}-1\right)^2\tau^{-1}+\left(1-e^{-2L/\tau}\right)\tau\right]\frac{Q_B}{2L^2}$$

"Problem" : when $L \to 0$, we get
$$var\left(Y_{\infty}(L)\right)\sim\frac{Q_B}{L}$$
which is not at all what was obtained while studying $\dot X(t)$.

**Am I wrong to expect $var(Y(t,L))$ to converge to $var(\dot X(t))$ when $L\to0$ ? Or have I made mistakes ?**

Comment: is the white noise zero-mean?

Comment: Yes. I'll add it to the op.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I'm now more clear on a number of things and can actually start answering (bits of) the question myself.

**The first result, that is
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}var\left(\dot X(t)\right)=\frac{Q_B}{\tau^2}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\tau}\right)$$
is in fact, wrong**, because $var(B(t))=Q_B\delta_t$ ($\delta_t$ being a Dirac) and **not** simply $Q_B$.

Additionally, $B(t)$ and $X(t)$ are **not** independant : since
$$X(t)=e^{-t/\tau}\left(X_0+\int_0^t e^{u/\tau}B(u)du\right)$$
we have
$$cov(B(t),X(t))=cov\left(B(t),e^{-t/\tau}\int_0^te^{+u/\tau}B(u)du\right)=e^{-2t/\tau}\int_0^tcov\left(B(t),e^{+u/\tau}B(u)\right)du=e^{-2t/\tau}\int_0^te^{+2u/\tau}Q_B\delta_tdu=Q_B$$

In the end, this first calculus would return
$$\lim_{t\to \infty}var\left(\dot X(t)\right)=\frac{Q_B}{\tau^2}\left(\delta_t+\frac{1}{2\tau}-1\right)$$
which is infinite/undefined due to the Dirac.

This is to be expected since the power of white noise is infinite/undefined, and $\dot X(t)$ is in fact simply scaled white noise plus a finite variable ($X(t)$).

Trying to evaluate $var(\dot X(t))$ for finite $t$ wouldn't make any more sense (it would be infinite/undefined as well).

**Now, let's see what we can do about $Y(t)$.**

Since my understanding of the problem has grown to a point that I've been able to correct some important mistakes + I realize my original question was probably poorly worded (I'd better use $dW_t$ instead of $B(t)dt$, I think I'll just create another cleaner, hopefully more rigorous question. I hope this is ok.